Alternative solution to Tailwind CSS dynamic classes for CSS Grid layout
Context
I am using Tailwind CSS and I am basically trying to create a table using Grid where the number of columns is the same number of items I have in an array called cols.
Then, I am trying to fill these cols with the same way of action col-start-${index} and col-end-${index}
Problem
using dynamic classes like grid-cols-${cols.length}, col-start-${index} col-end-${index} wont work. I know that number of items in cols will be changed in the future and I dont want to deal with this everytime I am adding\removing a column.
If anyone has an alternative dynamic way of action for this where I don't have to change the layout every time I'm adding\removing columns that would be great
My Code
import { modelers, cols, colsLengthForTW, tasks } from "@/util/stuff";
import ModelerRow from "@/components/ModelerRow";


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex flex-col min-h-screen p-24">
        <section className={`grid grid-cols-${cols.length} gap-3 px-8`}>
        {cols.map((thead, idx )=> {
          return<div key={thead+idx} className={`col-start-${idx+1} col-end-${idx+2} flex`}>
          {thead}
        </div>})}
        </section>
        <div className="grid grid-rows gap-8 text-lg font-semibold bg-white rounded-lg  shadow-lg">
        {modelers.map((modeler, idx )=> {
          return <ModelerRow key={modeler+idx} modeler={modeler} tasks={tasks} />
          })}
        </div>
    </main>
  );
}


You could consider using the style attribute like:
<main className="flex flex-col min-h-screen p-24">
  <section
    className="grid gap-3 px-8"
    style={{
      gridTemplateColumns: `repeat(${cols.length}, minmax(0, 1fr))`,
    }}
  >
    {cols.map((thead, idx )=> {
      return (
        <div
          key={thead+idx}
          className="flex"
          style={{ gridColumn: `${idx + 1} / ${idx + 2}` }}
        >


Had to add display: grid and remove the repetitive part, but your idea seems to work!
